# pyTelegrambotAPI problem with handling multiple conversations

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Good day all
My main question about telegram bot (I have a working one), i take input from user and then save it into lists and return information when they click certain inlinekeyboard buttons, however when i logging from another device i also see those inputs from another conversation, how can this problem be solved? attach a DB? is there a function or a class which can initiate multiple instances of conversations and depending on user return the values if they belong to him?
Or is it as simple as creating a class and then initiating the vars which will store the information within the class? or any other advice would be appriciated

here is a snippet of the code:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.data == "newpositions")
def set_positions(message):
    if len(pos_array) > 1:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Positions already set")
    else: 
        print(message)
        pos_num_reply = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "How many positions do you have?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(pos_num_reply, call_positions)

def call_positions(message):
    pos_count.append(int(float(message.text)))
    print("Pos_count array->", pos_count)
    if j < pos_count[0]:
        set_pos = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Set Position {j+1}")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(set_pos, set_position)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Your positions:{back_slash}{back_slash.join(map(str, pos_array))}")
        
def set_position(message):
    global j
    pos_to_save = float(message.text)
    pos_array.append(pos_to_save)
    j += 1
    call_positions(message)
############################### NEW POSITIONS END ###########################################################

############################### DEL POSITIONS START ###########################################################
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.data == "delpositions")
def delete_positions(message):
    pos_count.clear()
    pos_array.clear()
    global j
    j = 0
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"All Positions have been deleted")
    # bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=message.id, cache_time=60)
############################### DEL POSITIONS END ###########################################################

############################### ADD POSITION START ###########################################################
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.data == "addpositions")
def add_positions(message):
    pos_add_reply = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Enter a new position:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(pos_add_reply, add_position)

def add_position(message):
    pos_array.append(float(message.text))
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"New position added:{back_slash}{back_slash.join(map(str, pos_array))}")

############################### ADD POSITION END ###########################################################

############################### CLEAR POSITION START ###########################################################
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.data == "delaposition")
def del_a_position(message):
    if len(pos_array) < 1:
        positions(message)
    else:
        keyboard = []
        
        for i, button in enumerate(pos_array):
            keyboard.append([types.InlineKeyboardButton(button , callback_data=f"{button}")])
    
        reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, row_width=2)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"{back_slash}Which Position to remove:", reply_markup = reply_markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def delete_a_position(message):
    print(message.data)
    pos_to_delete = float(message.data)
    for i in pos_array:
        if i == pos_to_delete:
            pos_array.remove(i)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"{back_slash}Position {i} removed{back_slash}New Position list{back_slash}{back_slash.join(map(str, pos_array))}")`
```

been reading documentation but i havent stumbled across anything relevant

Answer (score 0):

in this case, it uses async functions.

- The async function executes functions from your code in no default order. an asynchronous function does not wait for one function to finish before executing the other, it can execute all of them simultaneously depending on the flow of the program.

#### Follow the examples

Import the `AsyncTeleBot` class and the asyncio library

- Exemple

```python
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot
import asyncio

bot = AsyncTeleBot(token='YOUR_TOKEN')

# YOUR CODE

asyncio.run(bot.polling(non_stop=True)) # THIS PART IS THE LAST LINE OF CODE
```

Now you can define the async functions

- Exemple

```python
async def add_positions(message):
    pos_add_reply = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Enter a new position:")
    await bot.register_next_step_handler(pos_add_reply, add_position)
```

- NOTE: `async` for the function and `await` for your bot actions, don't forget.

Do this for every function in your code.